# Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open '.next\static\development\_buildManifest.js' in next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, next.js

Although i check many other solutions i constantly run into this error

```
error - Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open '.next\static\development\_ssgManifest.js'
[Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open '.next\static\development\_ssgManifest.js'] {
  errno: -4082,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '.next\\static\\development\\_ssgManifest.js'
}
```

Does anyone know any solution it would help a lot
**Thanks**

Comment: Try restarting your pc and see if that solves the issue or the easiest hack you can try is closing all your terminals and disabling all your antiviruses to get rid of a blocker and try again. Hope that helps :)

Comment: yes closing and opening works but then it comes again what is the cause of this